# Estimating a the current probability of a changing random variable for a given number of trials.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I will explain this with a simple example as I don't quite know how to word this. I was taking a look at the statistics on the success rate of SpaceX landing their first stages. If you look at the complete statistics they have landed 136 of 147 attempts, giving a success rate of around 0.925.

however, this number does not reflect the current success rate, as one would expect the success probability to be increasing over time. In fact, if one assumes the rate of 0.925, their current streak of 62 consecutive landings seems incredibly unlikely to have happened.

My question is whether or not there exists a technique for analysing situations like this which would give an estimate of the current success rate. As of now I can think of just removing the first sqrt of the trials; however, this is just a guess of mine.

Comment: Anything one does is going to be model dependent.  It's not unreasonable to suppose something along the lines of "there are several different potential, independent, causes of error and over time we expect some of these to become less probable".  Perhaps one could even analyze each fail to see that some such factors might be responsible.  Not sure if that's the sort of thing you had in mind.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that it may just be about determining a model and fitting it. I was just wondering if there was any rigorous way to go about choosing such a model.

Comment: There isn't.  Especially in this sort of case...in other scenarios, the advice would be to take some of the data, build a model, and then apply that model to "clean" data.  But here, you only have the one time series and it isn't even very long.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help though.